# Evaluating the following sum

Tags: integration, summation, problem-solving

I have no idea how to solve evaluate this integral:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^a + 2^a + \cdots + n^a}{n^{1+a}}, a > -1$$

I want to set this up as some sort of integration since it is a large sum but I am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you squint a little to see a Riemann sum there?

Comment: So do some sort of approximation? Like find a left sum, right sum kind of thing?

Comment: I mean, write the sum in a slightly different way, so that it becomes obvious that it is a Riemann sum (and of what).

Comment: Okay I think I know what to do...

Comment: @InsigMath compare with $$\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=na}^{nb} f(i)$$

Comment: Yeah, that was basically my intention, thank you!

Comment: @InsigMath you're welcome. Just to point out, in general this also tells you that the first term in the closed form for $\sum i^a$ is $\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$

Comment: Hmm interesting! Thanks :)

Comment: @Sabyasachi That equation seems to be off by a few constants...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro if you're referring to $\frac1{n}$ then thanks for pointing out. It was a typo. Can't edit anymore. Anything else?

Comment: @Sabyasachi You are evaluating $f$ at $i=na$ to $i=nb$, in integer steps, but the integral only goes from $a$ to $b$. I think you need to evaulate from $a$ to $b$ in steps of $1/n$, that is $\sum_{i=na}^{nb}\frac1n f(\frac in)$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro ah yes. missed two $\frac1{n}$'s. Wasn't paying attention apparently. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nk^a}{n^{a+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\bigg(\frac kn\bigg)^a=\int_0^1x^adx=\bigg[\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\bigg]_0^1=\frac1{a+1}$$

Comment: Thank you, I actually calculated that! Can I ask a more general question though, why can't you do the sum of limits? I realize that trying to do that will get a $0$ but is it because we have infinite $n's$ that we can use that limit properly and must relate this to Riemann sums?

Comment: Yes. Imagine the following case: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\dfrac1n+\dfrac1n+\ldots+\dfrac1n}_{n\text{ times}}$